# TYPO3 multiple mail forms (tx_form) on one page?

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have two mail forms on one page but the second form just submits the first one. Are there some settings or typoscript I can add to make this work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the form wizard. In the tab "Form" you can overwrite the field "Prefix". TYPO3 uses this value in the submit button, like this:

```
<input id="field-10" value="Send" name="tx_form_form[my_prefix][10]" type="submit">
```

If you enter different prefixes for your forms, the submit buttons should know which one to submit.